# Negative exponential of an exponential random variable is a uniform random variable?

Tags: uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

I know that the negative log of a uniform random variable is an exponential random variable. I am trying to prove the reverse, but I seem to have arrived at something that doesn't make sense.

Define $Y \sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda)$, and $X = -\exp(Y)$.

\begin{align}
    P(X \leq x) = P(-\exp(Y) \leq x) = P(Y \geq -\ln(x)) \\
    = \int_{-\ln(x)}^{{\infty}} \lambda \exp (-\lambda y) dy
    = -\exp(- \lambda y) \big|_{-\ln(x)}^{\infty} \\
    = \exp(\lambda \ln(x)) \\
    = x^{\lambda}
\end{align}

If you take the derivative of this to get the pdf of $x$, you see that it is a function of $x$, which isn't constant, hence $X$ isn't a uniform random variable. So I am confused, is the negative exponential of a exponential random variable not a uniform random variable, or did I make a mistake in my derivation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix in red: what does have a $U(0,\,1)$ distribution is $\color{blue}{1-}\exp(-\color{red}{\lambda}Y)$, where the blue part is unnecessary but makes the transformation order-preserving. In fact, it's $Y$'s CDF, say $F$. This is no coincidence:$$P(F(Y)\le f)=P(Y\le F^{-1}(f))=F(F^{-1}(f))=f\implies F(Y)\sim U(0,\,1).$$

Comment: What do you mean by order-preserving?

Comment: @dd22205 $y_1\le y_2\implies1-\exp(-\lambda y_1)\le1-\exp(-\lambda y_2)$.

Comment: Ah I see. How can I use this to show that if $\lambda = 0.5$, then $1 - \exp(-\lambda Y)$ is $-2\log U(0,1)$? This seems to be what is implied by http://keyonvafa.com/box-muller-transform/

Comment: @dd22205 If we drop my blue part, $X=e^{-\lambda Y}\implies Y=-\lambda^{-1}\ln X$. BTW if you're studying that transform, you might soon move onto [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm studying transforms in general, and this is kind of all new to me. So far I've briefly looked into Box-Muller and using Cholesky Decomposition to create correlated random RVs from IID standard normal IVs. Do you have any suggestions for what other transforms are commonly encountered or useful to learn?

Comment: @dd22205 For starters, my answer did [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling). Then you can go through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-random_number_sampling).